# MongoDb: How to get Group by's total count as a flat count instead of in an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is hard for me to put in words, so I am going to try and explain with a code example:

[Working MongoDb Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oToxArwQL6v)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "countByStatus": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$status.name",
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "totalCount": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "countByStatus": [
      {
        "_id": "Approved",
        "count": 2
      },
      {
        "_id": "Rejected",
        "count": 1
      }
    ],
    "totalCount": [
      {
        "_id": null,
        "count": 3
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Desired Output:**

```
[
  {
    "countByStatus": [
      {
        "_id": "Approved",
        "count": 2
      },
      {
        "_id": "Rejected",
        "count": 1
      }
    ],
    "totalCount": 3 //totalCount is a flat count instead of array here
  }
]
```

I could execute the query get the result and then pick first element of `array[0].count` but I want to know if this could be done natively?

Answer (score 3):

It can be done in a single stage with [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/):

```
{
    $project: {
        countByStatus: 1,
        totalCount: {
            $let: {
                vars: { first: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$totalCount", 0 ] } },
                in: "$$first.count"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wGzpQI_I6H9)